# AspNetCore.Identity UserManager CreateAsync cannot save relationships

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a model like this:

```
public class UserIdentity : IdentityUser
{
    public User User { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Occupation Occupation { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public Ethnicity Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public GenderEnum Gender { get; set; }
}
```

the IdentityUser is in `AspNetCore.Identity` namespace. Also, I'm using [Urf.Core](https://github.com/urfnet/URF.Core) for my repository and service layer, and the Entity is for specifying trackable entities in that library.

in my Application layer I have a service for registering users and I use `UserManager<UserIdentity>` to save users.

```
public async Task Register(UserRegistrationDto dto)
    {
        var newUser = new User();

        var country = GetCountry(dto.CountryName);
        var city = GetCity(country, dto.CityName, dto.CityId.Value);

        var ethnicity = GetEthnicity(dto.EthnicityId.Value);
        var occupation = GetOccupation(dto.OccupationId.Value);

        newUser.Country = country;
        newUser.City = city;
        newUser.Occupation = occupation;
        newUser.Ethnicity = ethnicity;

        newUser.DateOfBirth = dto.DateOfBirth;

        newUser.Name = dto.Name;
        newUser.Surname = dto.Surname;
        newUser.Gender = (GenderEnum)dto.Gender.Value;

        _userService.Insert(newUser);

        var newIdentity = new UserIdentity {UserName = dto.Email, Email = dto.Email, User = newUser};
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newIdentity, dto.Password);

        //await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

**Code explanation:**

the `GetCountry` and `GetCity`, both check if the city and country exists or not, and if not it creates them. I insert the user and all its relations with Urf service in `_userService.Insert(newUser)` and save it all together in single transaction with again, Urf unit of work, `await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync()`

**The problem:**

placing `SaveChangesAsync()` before `_userManager.CreateAsync()`, creates the user, city, country and all without any problem. But if I call `_userManager.CreateAsync()`, ef throws exception 'Cannot insert explicit value for identity column...' for id column in country, city, and user tables.

I want to save the `UserIdentity` and rest of the relationships in one call of `SaveChanges()`, but looks like `_userManager.CreateAsync()` cannot save relations like the way `_unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync()` can.

**Temoporary solution:**

to get pass for now, I reversed the relations in `UserIdentity` and `User`, I create the identity first and if that succeeds I insert rest of them:

```
    public async Task Register(UserRegistrationDto dto)
    {
        var newIdentity = UserIdentity.CreateIdentity(dto.Email, dto.Email, dto.Phone);
        var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newIdentity, dto.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            var newUser = new User();

            var country = GetCountry(dto.CountryName);
            var city = GetCity(country, dto.CityName, dto.CityId.Value);

            var ethnicity = GetEthnicity(dto.EthnicityId.Value);
            var occupation = GetOccupation(dto.OccupationId.Value);

            newUser.Identity = newIdentity;
            newUser.Country = country;
            newUser.City = city;
            newUser.Occupation = occupation;
            newUser.Ethnicity = ethnicity;

            newUser.DateOfBirth = dto.DateOfBirth;

            newUser.Name = dto.Name;
            newUser.Surname = dto.Surname;
            newUser.Gender = (GenderEnum)dto.Gender.Value;

            _userService.Insert(newUser);

            await _unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

but as you can see, it saves them in two seperate transactions, if `_unitOfWork.SaveChangesAsync();` fails for any reason, the identity is created and I can't rollback (it is possible but dirty)

does anyone know why the problem I explained, happens?

Answer (score 0):

You neglected to post your full controller, particularly the services that are being injected, but based on your issue, I'm guessing you're injecting `UserManager<IdentityUser>`.

The type param here is what is actually going to be retrieved, persisted, etc. So, if you attempt to save a `UserIdentity` instance, it will be upcast to `IdentityUser` (which doesn't have your `User` property), and *that* is what's going to be created. If you need to work with `UserIdentity`, then you need to inject `UserManager<UserIdentity>`.

However, your design here is completely wrong. The whole point of the user type being generic is to allow extensibility. You should create a class that inherits from `IdentityUser` and specify any additional properties for your user directly there. You do not need and should not have a separate profile-style class added in via composition. In other words:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    public Occupation Occupation { get; set; }
    public Country Country { get; set; }
    public City City { get; set; }
    public Ethnicity Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public GenderEnum Gender { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<User>();
```

And in your controller, inject `UserManager<User>` and work with `User` directly. `UserIdentity` goes in the trash.

Comment: Well, I do inject `UserManager<UserIdentity>` already, so that is not the case. About throwing away UserIdentity, I really don't like the User object being messed up with identity concerns, especially cases where the consumer does not need to know anything about the identity of the User and vice versa. Maybe my naming is wrong about choosing User as its name. But thank you for your answer. I'll update my question for more details.